# Writing strings from a FIFO to a log file results sometimes in rubbish data being inserted

Tags: c, file-io, named-pipes, fifo

I have to get info from different processes through a FIFO aka named pipe. If I print the info I get from the process, it all looks fine. Once inserted into the log file I get some rubbish squares plus the data I added and I really don't know where this comes from.

A part of my code, if I print the message I get the correct message so it must have something to do with fprintf:

```
int fifoFd =  open("FIFOTest2",O_RDONLY);
    if(read(fifoFd, message, 200)>0){
    fprintf(logFile,"%s",message);
    fflush(logFile)
```

My fifo_write function:

```
void fifo_write(char * threadMessage)
{

  int fifoFd = open("FIFOTest2",O_WRONLY);

  char message[200];
  memset(message,0,sizeof(message)); //added because otherwise some bytes of message were uninitialised -> valgrind error Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
  logNumber++;
  snprintf(message,199,"%d %ld %s\n",logNumber, time(NULL),threadMessage);
  write(fifoFd,message,199);
  close(fifoFd);
}
```

Comment: The program that writes to the pipe, does it write ***null-terminated** byte strings*?

Comment: `read()` returns a value (the number of characters read, or -1) Use that value.

Comment: for what can i use that value?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude   i added my fifo_write function, aren't strings always null terminated?

Comment: @WannesVanderPerren it tells you how many bytes in the buffer are valid. You should not write more than this number of characters to your logfile.

Comment: You use the value returned by `read()` to ensure you do not use data not set by the `read()` call.  For example, `fprintf(logFile, "%.*s\n", nbytes, message);` where you have `int nbytes = read(…)` and you check for negative return values before you use `fprintf()`.

Comment: You write (unconditionally) 199 bytes to the pipe, but read 200 bytes. You also have no real error checking on the writing side. And as mentioned, you should really be using the value that `read` returns. But at least your string will always be null terminated.